# Is it wise to rely on default features of a programming language?

Tags: language-agnostic, default

Should I frequently rely on default values?

For example, in PHP, if you have the following:

```
<?php

$var .= "Value";

?>
```

This is perfectly fine - it works. But what if assignment like this to a previously unused variable is later eliminated from the language? (I'm *not* referring to just general assignment to an unused variable.)

There are countless examples of where the default value of something has changed and so much existing code was then useless.

On the other hand, without defaults, there is a lot of code redundancy.

What is the proper way of dealing with this?

Comment: For those who don't know PHP well, you should explain what `.=` does.  Does it set `$var` to `"Value"` if it was unset earlier?

Comment: It is like the += operator in C++. It appends to a string. Currently it will just set $var to 'Value' if $var is blank.

Comment: @George: have you ever heard of a feature being removed from a language?

Comment: A default changed, not necessarily a feature removed.

Comment: @John: I have frequently heard of features being removed from languages. Also defaults being changed. For example in 2002 PHP famously changed the default behaviour of George's example code, because the previous behaviour was so utterly, atrociously stupid. The default value of `register_globals` went from true to false.

Comment: @Steve: which languages? PHP and which other? And (I don't know PHP) how old was PHP at the time?

Comment: Just off the top of my head, C (removed implicit function declarations in C99). Python 3 is a backward-incompatible release, for example it removes the `print` statement. PHP was 7 years old in 2002. In general, search for X+"backward-incompatible change". For example here's a note than in Java, any new public method technically removes a "feature" - the ability for subclasses to have a method of the same name and parameters but different return type ;-) http://java.dzone.com/news/the-capability-pattern-future-

Comment: I guess you can argue that by definition a backward-incompatible version is a "different language", not a removal of features. In which case, OK, languages never remove features. But people frequently accidentally move their code to a new language when they take an update, without necessarily realising it's a different language from before, or need to move to a new language in order to get bugfixes, or use a library written for one language in another language. Whatever you *call* it, that's what George is concerned will happen to him.

Comment: I should probably add that I don't think the PHP authors were stupid to have defined the old behaviour (I'm sure it seemed like a good idea at the time), or to make a breaking change once it was realised that the old behaviour was stupid and that any real-life PHP program needed either to switch it off, or to very carefully ensure it didn't kick in accidentally. What was realised between 1995 and 2002 was just that if you're going to permit implicitly initialised variables at all (as dynamic languages often do), you shouldn't init them with malicious data by default ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, the odds of a language changing drastically once it reaches a certain level of acceptance are pretty low.

To me, each language comes with a (sometimes more or less) unique set of features. Not using those because they just might disappear some day seems shortsighted. Naturally, don't use esoteric features just for the sake of doing so -- make sure you follow usual principles of readability and best practices for your language of choice, but otherwise I see no need to discriminate against particular features.

Comment: So you're saying go ahead if the feature is well-established?

Comment: And if it's actually documented to be a feature, rather than an accident of the most common implementation of the language: Yes, go ahead.

Comment: Yes. Depending on what the feature is, how well it's established might not even matter. As Brooks Moses said in his answer, if the feature in question is commonly used, you're likely in the clear. If it's an odd case or a side-effect, than it's more likely to get removed. But in the end, you gotta use something, so you might as well go with what the language gives you. :)

Comment: I assume you would use VB6 as a prime example?  How about Python 2 vs. 3?  Or PHP4 to 5?  I think the right perspective is that when there's a committee behind a standard, the languages tend not to change in damaging ways.   Otherwise all bets are off.

Comment: Ya. I started using Python 3 only to discover that it was VASTLY different than Python 2.

Answer (score 3):

Default-value features of a programming language, if actually a documented part of the standard rather than just an accident of the implementation (which many past "default initializations" have been), are no different from any other features of a programming language.  You might as well ask if it's wise to rely on anything else in the language, and the answer regardless of wisdom is that there's no choice -- you have to rely on something, and anything could hypothetically be changed in a future version.

Of course, if the thing that you're relying on is a commonly-used feature of the language, rather than an odd corner case, then there's a lot more chance that it will be retained in future versions.  In addition, if you're concerned about such things, it's wise to choose a well-established language that has a history of maintaining backwards compatibility.  Some languages take great pains to make sure that older code runs in the new version of the language, and some less so.

So, that's the general answer.  The specific answer about default values is that it depends on the particular case, the language in question, and so forth.  You can have absolute ironclad reliance on the fact that global static variables in C will be zero at program start.  Some other cases are rather notably less reliable.

Comment: I'm guessing you use C a lot.

Comment: True, I do -- and I know my answer's skewed a bit from that, and have tried to correct for it.  But I've also worked on compiler implementations for Fortran, which has changed almost to the point of unrecognizability in the last 50 years, and I'm remembering discussions on what backwards compatibility to support or not support in the compiler when the language changed.

Comment: PHP doesn't have a standard.  It doesn't even have a published grammer.

Answer (score 0):

If something is a defined feature of a language, it's probably pretty safe to rely on it.

Where you should be wary of relying on functionality is when you get into areas where you're dealing with behavior that is either unspecified, or if you're "misusing" a feature by using it for something completely other than what it was intended for.

Since "default value of a string" is pretty much a mainline scenario, it's probably safe.  What's more dangerous is that if you happen to declare that variable earlier, you can get hit by it changing the expected value as an unintended side effect.

Basically, if you're not abusing a language feature, or relying on undefined behavior, you should probably worry more about unintended side effects in your code than you should worry about the language changing - especially if the language is mature.